# Android OS not identifying orientation changes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I have the following folders inside /res directory to support different screen densities and orientation.

```
/layout
/layout-land
/layout-small
/layout-small-land
/layout-large
/layout-large-land
```

In the above XMLs, all that is different is alignment between components. For instance, in portrait:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout3" />
```

whereas in landscape,

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"        //widens the margin space
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout3" />
```

However, when the orientation is changed, the XML corresponding to portrait is being used.

Here is the AndroidManifest code snippet.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
```

I tested the app in emulator with Android 2.2 and 3.7" screen. Is there anything I missed out?

Comment: Are there layout xml in all -land folder ? I mean, are you sure you are working correct -land directory ?

Answer (score 2):

> However, when the orientation is changed, the XML corresponding to portrait is being used.

That is because that is what you told Android to do, via:

`android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize`

Delete that attribute, and Android will destroy and recreate your activity, applying your new layout resources.

With that attribute in place, it is *your* job to somehow load those new layout resources, in `onConfigurationChanged()`.

Comment: Mine is a tabbed application. Each tab, upon load, fetches data from the server using AsyncTask. If I change as you said above, will it load the page each time the orientation is changed?

Comment: @Renjith: Tabs should not be fetching "data from the server using `AsyncTask`", at least not blindly.